# SSH password requested when in Tmux

Tags: ssh, password, tmux, key-authentication, ssh-agent

When I connect to my remote machine I do authenticate using a rsa key (I think is rsa, don't remember).

If I do ssh from a regular shell I get logged on the machine without a password. However if I do ssh from within tmux I get asked for a password.

What is different within tmux that I get asked a password and the ssh key is not used? How can I get to not type the password from within tmux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your tmux session was started before your ssh agent was started, so the SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID variables are not set inside it. There are two ways to solve this. You can either copy those variables into the tmux session or run ssh-agent inside tmux to get them set, then run ssh-add to add the key to your ssh agent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I have logged onto the remote machine using the ssh key, so that all relevant variables were set. Then started tmux (and even restored my session with tmux-resurrect) and now it indeed connects using the ssh key. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may also find the man page useful, see http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1 and search for the section ENVIRONMENT where it talks about the set-environment and show-environment commands.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the answers to a similar question on the Superuser SE site, [Can I re-attach SSH key forwarding through a disconnected Screen session](https://superuser.com/questions/438811/can-i-re-attach-ssh-key-forwarding-through-a-disconnected-screen-session/439006#439006).  The answers are likely the same.